# Sub query or not to write this query?

Tags: sql

My SQL query:

```
select 
    *, 
    (select sum(Amount) as TotalAmount 
     from Payment 
     where Customer.Id = Payment.CustomerId) 
from Customer
```

The result:

```
Id - CustomerName - CustomerPhoneNumber - TotalAmount
1  - TestUser     - TestLastName        - 3000   
2  - TestUser2    - TestLastName2       - 2500
```

---

This is working as I expected. But are there any better ways to get same result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's MySQL, then you can do this...

```
SELECT
  Customer.*,
  SUM(Payment.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM
  Customer
LEFT JOIN
  Payment
    ON Payment.CustomerId = Customer.Id
GROUP BY
  Customer.id
```

In other varieties of SQL, you need to GROUP BY everything that is selected but not an aggregate.

```
SELECT
  Customer.Id,
  Customer.Name,
  Customer.PhoneNumber,
  SUM(Payment.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM
  Customer
LEFT JOIN
  Payment
    ON Payment.CustomerId = Customer.Id
GROUP BY
  Customer.Id,
  Customer.Name,
  Customer.PhoneNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it with `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` :

```
select 
a.*, sum(b.Amount) as TotalAmount    
from Customer a
left join Payment on (a.Id = b.CustomerId)
GROUP BY a.Id -- for mysql only, for other RDMS you have to list all Customer fields
```

Or

```
 select 
a.*, b.TotalAmount    
from Customer a
left join 
(SELECT CustomerId, SUM(Amount) as TotalAmount 
 FROM Payment GROUP BY CustomerId)b  ON (b.CustomerId = a.Id)
```